# Select users who have won in different categories

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, count, having

I need to select the users who have won at least 1 round in all of the different competitions.

I have the following table sctructure:

`results`

| id | round_id | user_id | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

`rounds`

| id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

`categories` championship

| id | competition_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

`competitions` team

| id | competition_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Competition A |
| 2 | Competition B |

Now let's say Bob has won at least 1 round in both Competition A and B each, he needs to show up in the list. But Joe, who's won 1 round in Competition A but nothing in Competition B, must not show up.

I tried writing a script like this, but I can see the flaw in my logic. It's looking for a row where the round_id is both 1 and 2 is impossible.

```
SELECT user_id FROM results WHERE 
    (result = 1 AND round_id IN 
        (SELECT id FROM rounds WHERE category_id IN 
            (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE competition_id = 7)
        )
    ) AND 
    (result = 1 AND round_id IN 
        (SELECT id FROM rounds WHERE category_id IN 
            (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE competition_id = 8)
        )
    ) AND 
    (result = 1 AND round_id IN 
        (SELECT id FROM rounds WHERE category_id IN 
            (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE competition_id = 9)
        )
    )
    GROUP BY driver_id
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want results specifically for competition_ids 7, 8 and 9 or for all competitions in the table competitions?

Comment: Yes. It should show Bob won at least once in competition 7, 8 and 9. So let's say Joe won in competition 6, 7 and 8, he wont show up, because of the criteria (7,8,9 - in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `results` to `rounds` and `categories` (`competitions` is not needed because `competition_id` exists in `categories`).
Then filter the rows  for only the users who won at least one round and aggregate by user with the condition in the `HAVING` clause for the user that all 3 `competition_id`s are returned:

```
SELECT rs.user_id
FROM results rs
INNER JOIN rounds rd ON rd.id = rs.round_id
INNER JOIN categories cg ON cg.id = rd.category_id
WHERE rs.result = 1 AND cg.competition_id IN (7, 8, 9)
GROUP BY rs.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cg.competition_id) = 3;
```